# How to insert all the data from asp repeater table to another table in database

Tags: c#, mysql, repeater

I want to insert all the data that are bind in the repeater to another table in database when I click the checkout button. *NOTE I have two tables in database TABLE A is for the Shopping Cart which I have used repeater with and TABLE B is for all the Orders that will be combined ones the Check Out button is clicked. The two tables have the same columns except for the Primary Key (ID). Both have 20 columns

```
 protected void lbtnCheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);
        string cmdText = "@INSERT INTO Order_TB SELECT * FROM ShoppingCart";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        //===== Execute Query.
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //===== close the connection.
        con.Close();
    }
```

[ASP Repeater Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEV2d.png)